# Not able to close the channel and connection for rabbitmq programmatically in java

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Wanted to close the channel and connection when cancelling the consumer

@Service
public class RabbitMQConsumer{

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMQConsumer.class);

@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

private Connection connection;

private Channel channel;

public String consumeMessage(String queueName, Boolean flag, DeliverCallback deliverCallback, CancelCallback cancelCallback) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    channel = connection.createChannel(true);
    return channel.basicConsume(queueName, flag, deliverCallback, cancelCallback);
}

public void cancelConsumer(String consumerTag) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    if(channel != null && channel.isOpen()){
       channel.basicCancel(consumerTag);
       channel.close();
    }
    if(connection != null && connection.isOpen()){
        logger.info("connection.isOpen() "+connection.isOpen());
        connection.close();
        logger.info("after closing, checking connection.isOpen() "+connection.isOpen());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What web container are you using? If it's Spring you'll have to use `@Predestroy` https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy

Comment: I have updated the question, Can you please check

Comment: Can you check if channel and connection is not null and isOpen() and close down if it is. Next step, might need to add await for some time.

Comment: Yes @VinitMore  the connection is not null, and isOpen() is true but we are still not able to close the connection